# not foundsh: 2: error comes while exectutin a shell command?

Tags: shell

when i run sh backuptest.sh, following error comes .So is it issue with the code or  my shell

```
result :
: not foundsh: 2: backuptest.sh:
: not foundsh: 4: backuptest.sh:
: not foundsh: 6: backuptest.sh:
: not foundsh: 7: backuptest.sh:



content of backuptest.sh
#!/bin/sh -e
location=`date +%Y%m%d`.sql
mysqldump -u root -proot spider_db > $location
```

Comment: ls /bin/sh does that works?

Comment: looks like your script contains DOS-style line endings. Try `dos2unix`

Comment: @glennjackman you legend!

Answer (score 7):

remove `#!/bin/sh -e` and try

```
dos2unix backuptest.sh
```

then execute again with

```
./backuptest.sh
```